Dual program of the optimization
I have the following primal program as
$$\min c$$
subject to
$$\int_0^1p_tdt = 1$$
$$\int_0^1 (t+1)p_t dt\le \frac{\lambda}{1-\exp(-\lambda)}$$
$$\int_0^{t'}(t+1) p_tdt + t' \int_{t'}^1p_tdt\le ct' \quad \forall t'\in[0,1]$$
$$p_t\ge 0\quad \forall t \in [0,1]$$
I want to show that the dual program has the following form:
$$\max \lambda_d - \lambda_c \cdot\frac{\lambda}{1-\exp(-\lambda)}$$
subject to
$$\int_0^1 t\lambda_tdt \le 1$$
$$\lambda_d -(t'+1)\lambda_c\le \int_0^{t'}t\lambda_tdt + (t'+1)\int_{t'}^1\lambda_tdt \quad\forall t' \in [0,1]$$
$$\lambda_c,\lambda_t\ge 0\quad\forall t\in[0,1]$$
where $\lambda_d,\lambda_c,\lambda_t$ are dual variables corresponding to first, second, and third primal constraints. I have attempted the following
$$L(c,p_t, \lambda_d,\lambda_c,\lambda_t) = c +\lambda_d\bigg(\int_0^1p_tdt - 1\bigg) +\lambda_c\bigg(\int_0^1 (t+1)p_t dt- \frac{\lambda}{1-\exp(-\lambda)} \bigg) + \int_0^1\lambda_{t'}\bigg( \int_0^{t'}(t+1) p_tdt + t' \int_{t'}^1p_tdt - ct' \bigg) dt' $$
After some manipulations, I got
$$ L(c,p_t, \lambda_d,\lambda_c,\lambda_t) = c \bigg(1 - \int_0^1\lambda_{t'}t'dt' \bigg) - \lambda_d - \lambda_c\frac{\lambda}{1-\exp(-\lambda)} + \int_0^1p_t\bigg(\lambda_d +\lambda_c(t+1) + (t+1)\int_t^1 \lambda_{t'}dt' + \int_0^t\lambda_{t'}t' dt' \bigg) dt$$
However, I don't know how to derive from here to the given dual above. Any helps are appreciated!
